# Scraping Website. Unable automate a user click during scrape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, phantomjs

Attempting to scrape a website. In order to do so, I want to automate clicking a button. I can't seem to get the button to do anything.

**Link:** http://shop.nordstrom.com/s/polo-ralph-lauren-pajama-pants/2849416

**Website Stack**: ReactJS, JQueryJS

**Button Selector:** #‎product‬-selection-2849416 > section.color-filter > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span > span.image-sprite-image.cover > span > img

**Attempts**

JQuery click, mousedown, touchstart and native click... In Chrome Dev Tools Console.

```
$("‪#‎product‬-selection-2849416 > section.color-filter > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span > span.image-sprite-image.cover > span > img").click()

$("#product-selection-2849416 > section.color-filter > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span > span.image-sprite-image.cover > span > img")[0].click()

$("#product-selection-2849416 > section.color-filter > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span > span.image-sprite-image.cover > span > img").mousedown()

$('#product-selection-2849416 > section.color-filter > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span > span.image-sprite-image.cover > span > img').trigger('touchstart');
```

PhantomJS sendEvent function... Through PhantomJS headless browser.

```
var webpage = require('webpage');
var page = webpage.create();
var href = "http://shop.nordstrom.com/s/polo-ralph-lauren-pajama-pants/2849416";
page.open(href, function (status) {
    var elem = "#product-selection-2849416 > section.color-filter > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span > span.image-sprite-image.cover > span > img";
    var rect = page.evaluate(function(elem) {
        return $(elem)[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    }, elem);

    function computeCenter(bounds) {
        var x = Math.round(bounds.left + bounds.width / 2);
        var y = Math.round(bounds.top  + bounds.height / 2);
        return [x, y];
    }

    var cor = computeCenter(rect);
    page.sendEvent('click', cor.x, cor.y, 'left');
    setTimeout(function() {
        page.render('websiteAfterClick.png');
        page.close();
    }, 1000);
}
```

And HTML Events... In Chrome Dev Tools Console.

```
var elem = $("#product-selection-2849416 > section.color-filter > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span > span.image-sprite-image.cover > span > img")[0];
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
var center_x = 1, center_y = 1;
try {
    var pos = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    center_x = Math.floor((pos.left + pos.right) / 2);
    center_y = Math.floor((pos.top + pos.bottom) / 2);
} catch(e) {}
evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 1, 1, 1, center_x, center_y, false, false, false, false, 0, elem);
```

React Test Utils...  Through PhantomJS headless browser.

```
var webpage = require('webpage');
var page = webpage.create();
var href = "http://shop.nordstrom.com/s/polo-ralph-lauren-pajama-pants/2849416";
page.open(href, function (status) {
   page.includeJs("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.6/react-with-addons.js", function() {
        var elem = "#product-selection-2849416 > section.color-filter > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span > span.image-sprite-image.cover > span > img";
        page.evaluate(function(elem) {
            React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.click($(elem)[0]);
        }, elem);

        setTimeout(function() {
            page.render('websiteAfterClick.png');
            page.close();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Hacky attempt. The website features a select with the same options as the button I want to click.... In Chrome Dev Tools Console.

```
$('#product-selection-2849416 > section.color-filter > div > select').val('Black Royal Oxford').change();

$('#product-selection-2849416 > section.color-filter > div > select').val('Black Royal Oxford').trigger('change');
```

**Ideas**

Figure out a way to extract props inside their React Components. They also contain the data I desire. Not sure how to do so yet...

Use WebDriver & Selenium to create a click. Not sure about the integration with PhantonJS.

Find the function associated with the click handler, and attempt to call it. Working on this...

Using an XPath Clicker. Not sure how to do this. Can't find many resources online.

**Conclusion**

Can anyone here help me? Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. PhantomJS 2.0.x is known to hide errors. You can try 1.9.8,

Comment: I am using PhantomJS 2.1.1. For all the above tests, I had onConsoleMessage and OnError registered. 

I had onResourceRequested to reject loading any image resources. 

I added the example code in http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html and http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html

Comment: I registering onResourceError and onResourceTimeout. I got 
`Unable to load resource (#23URL:)
Error code: 301. Description: Protocol "" is unknown`. This was before I attempted to use Phantomjs to sendEvents to the page and only during page open.

Comment: Hm, no idea what this means. Try to increase the viewport.

Comment: My viewport is set at 
        `page.viewportSize = {
          width: 1366,
          height: 768
        };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I debugged their code a little and it looks like they hook up to mousedown/up and not click. The code below should work:

```
    var el = jQuery("#product-selection-2849416 > section.color-filter > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span > span.image-sprite-image.cover > span > img")[0];

    var evtMouseDown = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
    bubbles: true, cancelable: true, cancelBubble: false,
    defaultPrevented: false, isTrusted: true,
    button: 0,buttons: 1, which: 1, view: window
    });
    var evtMouseUp = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {
    bubbles: true, cancelable: true, cancelBubble: false,
    defaultPrevented: false, isTrusted: true,
    button: 0, buttons: 1, which: 1, view: window
    });

    el.dispatchEvent(evtMouseDown);
    el.dispatchEvent(evtMouseUp);
```